# Why can't my GPU be used when it is largely available?

Tags: pytorch

[image]

As you can see, the gpu 3 is 0% used, and only 11MB memory is used. But when I try to use this gpu on PyTorch or Tensorflow, it gives an error:

```
return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() else None, non_blocking)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory
```

Why can't I use them?

Comment: Did you specify gpu3, for example with `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=3` or `device="cuda:3"`?

Comment: device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"): This automatically currently available GPU.

Comment: "cuda" will go to gpu 0 by default. "Available" means pytorch has access to it, but doesn't guarantee it has enough memory for your program. Using `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=3 python your_script.py` will let your program think that gpu 3 is gpu 0, which solves the problem. Or you can change "cuda" to "cuda:3" inside the script. The two methods don't work simultaneously, of course.

Comment: RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid device ordinal, if I use cuda:3 specification.

Comment: If I use the command-line version, how can I specify the 'device' variable? PyTorch needs it.

Comment: Did the two methods I suggested above work? Note that they can't be used simultaneously. If you specify the environment variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=3` in the command line, there is no need to change "cuda" to "cuda:3" in the script

Comment: cuda:3 gives the error 'RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid device ordinal'. The command line version sees to be working.

Comment: I know why. When I use "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=3" at command line, how do I define the 'device' variable in the script?

Comment: Not strange, this is a separate issue. You need to put tensor back to CPU before converting them to numpy arrays: `embeddings = outputs[1].cpu().detach().numpy().tolist()`

Comment: The error message says that 'cuda:0', but the '0' is used by other programs.  I used: device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"), then CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=3 python bert_node_text_embedding.py. Is this still using cuda:0 or 3?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238419/discussion-between-ihdv-and-marlon).

Comment: Sorry but I seem to have some trouble opening the chat site. Basically when you use `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=3` in the command line, you should use "cuda:0" or just "cuda" in your script, because your program now thinks gpu3 is the only gpu available. that is why inside the program the error says "cuda:0"

Comment: @ihdv, but if I use the command line version, I can't use nohup. If I use nohup, it gives an error.

Comment: There are other alternatives. If you have tmux installed I think it is more convenient than nohup. If not, you can use argparse to take options in the command line to specify the gpu. For example, if you have `args.gpu_id`, and then do `device=f"cuda:{args.gpu_id}"`. If you are not familiar with them, you should check them out. It is unlikely I explain all these in the comments.

Comment: Yes. The main thing is still, why device = torch.device("cuda:3") produces 'RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid device ordinal'? If I change to cuda:0, 1, 2, it gives an out of memory error, which makes more sense, since they are being used by other programs.

Comment: I am not sure why. Maybe you can check if it works with a simple program that creates a tensor on gpu3.

Comment: Yes. I will do that.

Comment: Did you check torch.cuda.device_count() in your script?, without CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=3 .....  Does it return 3 or 4?